# How to send data to the server without refreshing the page in vuejs?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, vue.js, post

I'm doing a CRUD with vue-cli and nodejs on the server side. So I have a form like this

```html
<template>
  <div id="formRoot">
    <div class="form" >
      <form @submit.prevent="sendToTable" action="/create" method="post">
      Name
      <input type="text" v-model="row.name" name="name" />
      Price
      <input type="number" name="price" v-model="row.price"  />
      Description
      <textarea v-model="row.description" rows="3" name="desc"/>
      <input type="submit" id="button" value="SAVE" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <form class="" action="create" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
 </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>

 export default{
   data(){
     return{
       row: {
         name: '',
         price: '',
         description: ''
       }
     }
   },
   methods: {
     sendToTable() {
       console.log(this.row);
       this.$parent.addToTable(this.row);
     }
   }
 }


 </script>
```

the @submit.prevent is for avoid the page refreshing and of course I have a method named sendToTable.
 
in node I have this:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const morgan = require('morgan');

  const app = express();

  //middlewares
  app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')));
  app.use(morgan());

  app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body);

  });

  const port = 3000;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
  });
```

the problem is that the server cant get the post request, I think is because the @prevent.default property.
I tried sending a post request with postman and it works, so I'm sure the problem is in the frontend.
What should i do? How are actually coded those single page web apps that can send data to the server?

Comment: What does `sendToTable` do?

Comment: add the form data to another vue component

Comment: No, I mean literally what does it do? [Add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61625434/edit). If it's your submit handler, it should be posting the data to your backend

Comment: Is your server expecting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post body or `application/json`? What method are you using in Postman?

Comment: i use this middleware   app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false})); in postman i used post method of course

Comment: how can i post the data from the submit handler?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually post your form data via an HTTP request. You can use a library like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (very popular) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (check the [supported browsers list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility)).

Another thing you appear to be doing is calling a method on this component's parent. That goes against Vue's [*one-way data flow*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) and isn't optimal. The better solution is to have your component *emit* an event with the attached data.

For example (using `fetch`)

```html
<form @submit.prevent="sendToTable" method="post" action="/create">
```

```js
methods: {
  async sendToTable ($event) {
    const form = $event.target
    // post form as a regular "submit" would
    let res = await fetch(form.action, {
      method: form.method,
      body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form))
    })
    if (res.ok) {
      // emit the "row-added" event to the parent
      this.$emit('row-added', { ...this.row }) // using spread syntax to break references
    } else {
      // you might want to do something else here in case of an error
      console.error(res)
    }
  }
}
```

and in your parent component (assuming the child component is named `RowAdder`)

```html
<RowAdder @row-added="addToTable"/>
```